# How to test a PersistentMap item is correctly saved to storage?

Tags: nearprotocol

I have a function that takes a number of values, creates a new model, and then saves this in storage via a `PersistentMap`.

I would like to test that the item is successfully saved in storage. This is how I'm going about it:

```
    it("saves a new item to storage", () => {
      VMContext.setCurrent_account_id("test_account_id");

      contract.createMyPersistantMapItem(
        "value 1",
        "value 2",
        "value 3"
      );
   
      expect(storage.hasKey("myPersistantMap::test_account_id")).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

However the test fails with the following:

```
  [Actual]: false
[Expected]: Truthy
   [Stack]: RuntimeError: unreachable
            at node_modules/@as-pect/assembly/assembly/internal/assert/assert (wasm-function[53]:0xd71)
            at start:src/simple/__tests__/index.unit.spec~anonymous|0~anonymous|0~anonymous|0 (wasm-function[130]:0x2a84)
            at node_modules/@as-pect/assembly/assembly/internal/call/__call (wasm-function[134]:0x2aac)
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Also I would like to test the values in the item are correct. In the [todos example](https://github.com/near-examples/crud-tutorial/blob/main/todos-crud-contract/assembly/__tests__/index.spec.ts) the created todo is returned from the function that creates it, and then this returned value is tested. Is this the best way of doing things to make testing easier?

EDIT

This is the `createMyPersistantMapItem` function - edited a bit to make things clearer:

```
export function createMyPersistantMapItem(
    blah1: string,
    blah2: string,
    blah3: string,
  ): void {
    const accountId = context.sender;
  
    assert(
      !storage.hasKey("myPersistantMap::" + accountId),
      "Item already exists"
    );
  
    const newPersistantMapItem = new PersistantMapItem(
      blah1,
      blah2,
      blah3
    );
  
    myPersistantMap.set(accountId, newPersistantMapItem);
  }
```

Comment: How does your `createMyPersistantMapItem` function look like? You can also test the map from the contract directly, instead of testing storage.

Comment: Thanks @John - I've added the function to my question.

Comment: @John So regarding testing the map from the contract, do you mean returning `newPersistantMapItem` from `createMyPersistantMapItem` and then testing that? Ideally though I would like to also test that the item has been saved to storage with the correct key.

Comment: I thought you could access the persistentMap like this: `expect(contract.myPersistantMap.contains('test_account_id'))` instead of accessing storage. Then you save a couple of steps, and it should basically be the same as testing storage. Testing storage directly is also fine though. Does `myPersistentMap` use the "myPersistantMap" prefix when initialized? Does `PersistantMapItem` use the `@nearBingden` annotation on the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About the first question:**

Does `myPersistentMap` use the "myPersistantMap" prefix when initialized? Does `PersistantMapItem` use the @nearBingden annotation on the class?

Also, in your test, I think you should use

```
VMContext.setSigner_account_id("test_account_id") 

//instead of
VMContext.setCurrent_account_id("test_account_id")
```

Because you are using `context.sender` when you call `createMyPersistantMapItem`

**About the second question:**

> In the todos example the created todo is returned from the function that creates it, and then this returned value is tested. Is this the best way of doing things to make testing easier?

This question is primarily opinion based, so I can only answer for myself. Testing the returned value is completely fine. In a smart contract however, I would probably test if the value is actually stored on the contract. And I think they are doing that in the TODO example. They just use the ID of the generated TODO to do a query on the smart contract.

```
const a = Todo.insert("Drink water");
// They use the id of the todo (a) to check if it was actually stored, and is in fact the same object. I think this is fine.
expect(getById(a.id)).toStrictEqual(a);
```

Comment: Yep, the "myPersistantMap" prefix and @nearBingden annotation are being used. The issue was with using `VMContext.setCurrent_account_id("test_account_id")` - changing to `VMContext.setSigner_account_id("test_account_id") ` fixed the issue and I now have passing tests :) `expect(contract.myPersistantMap.contains('test_account_id')` as you suggested worked as well - I didn't realise that data was accessible via the contract - I just thought I would have to always query the contract's storage. Anyway, all good now, thanks for your help again!